# Connecting to Astra DB from Spring Boot app, getting AuthenticationException

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver, datastax-astra

[s0] Authentication error (AuthenticationException: Authentication error on node cdbd07ee-81fe-4adf-85e4-34338172ad24-asia-south1.db.astra.datastax.com/:29042:087b610b-271c-4e87-940d-65f26a2875be: 
Node cdbd07ee-81fe-4adf-85e4-34338172ad24-asia-south1.db.astra.datastax.com/:29042:087b610b-271c-4e87-940d-65f26a2875be 
requires authentication (org.apache.cassandra.auth.PasswordAuthenticator), 
but no authenticator configured)

This is the application.yml file.

spring:
data:
cassandra:
keyspace-name: main
username: ********
password: ********
schema-action: create-if-not-exists
request:
timeout: 10s
connection:
connect-timeout: 10s
init-query-timeout: 10s

datastax.astra:
secure-connect-bundle: secure-connect.zip

astra.db:
id: ********
region: asia-south1
keyspace: main
application.token: AstraCS:*****:*****

Comment: Please remove your credentials from you post, this is a security issue

Answer (score 2):

You need to customize the `CqlSession` by adding the secure connect bundle. With Spring Data you use a `CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer` as follow :

1/ Create a Bean to receive your property `datastax.astra`

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datastax.astra")
public class DataStaxAstraProperties {
    private File secureConnectBundle;
    //getter and setters.
}
```

2/ Use this bean to customize this session

```
@Bean
public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer sessionBuilderCustomizer(DataStaxAstraProperties astraProperties) {
    Path bundle = astraProperties.getSecureConnectBundle().toPath();
    return builder -> builder.withCloudSecureConnectBundle(bundle);
}
```

Here is a working sample:

- https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/spring-data-starter

You might be interested in the Astra Spring Boot Starter:

- https://github.com/datastax/astra-sdk-java/wiki/Astra-SDK-Quickstart